# validate FileFiled URL in django

Tags: html, django

I have a upload view:

views.py

```
def upload(request):

     if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
                newdoc.save()

                # Redirect to the document list after POST
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wiki.views.upload'))
        else:
            form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

        # Load documents for the list page
        documents = Document.objects.all()

        return render_to_response(
            'wiki/upload.html',
            {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

and my template
upload.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{%block title%}Upload Documents{%endblock%}

{%block content%}
    <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
    {% if documents %}
        <ul>
        {% for document in documents %}
            <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No documents.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
    <form action="{% url upload %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.docfile.help_text }}
        {{ form.docfile.label_tag }}
        {{ form.docfile.errors }}
        {{ form.docfile }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

{%endblock%}
```

I am uploading some files at the specified location under {MEDIA_ROOT} and it shows on the server but if I delete the file from that folder, the file name still shows on the webpage.

How do I validate and then display the uploaded file using my template.

Answer (score 0):

In the view or in a templatetag you can have the next code. f is the file

```
try:
    exists_file = f.size()
except IOError:
    exists_file = False
```

Comment: @ Goin can u please explain by putting the code in my above code snippet..thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a reverse link from the file system to django - if you upload a file to the directory, a new entry will not be added to the database, and similarly if you delete a file from the directory, the record won't be deleted from the database.

If you delete a file from the server, you need to delete that entry from the database as well. This will keep your file list in sync with what is actually available on the server.

Comment: so u mean to say, I need to add some code to check whether the file exists or not and if not delete it after documents = Document.objects.all() and then return.... if possible can u mention the code snap also. Thanks